# Simple command on wake from suspend

Tags: kubuntu

I am using Kubuntu 18.10 and I would like to run a simple script every time a computer wakes from suspend. The command is `xdotool mousemove 850 82 click 1` and that is all. I have already checked everything I was able to find here. For example I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
post)
xdotool mousemove 850 82 click 1
;;
esac
```

script was in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`

and it did not work at all. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: welcome to ask Ubuntu for this site if there is more than one line of code you should use code blocks (new line then 4 spaces in front of each line). see [commonly-accepted-formatting-guidelines](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15446/lets-agree-on-some-commonly-accepted-formatting-guidelines) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are scripts that get run at Suspend/Resume/Hibernate/Wake times, but they run in a "system" context, not a "User/GUI" one. Read `man pm-action` [online](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/pm-action.8.html).

You could wrap your `xdotool` in a `bash` script, so you can access the GUI (if you're logged in). Put the line

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

early in your script.

NOTE: `DISPLAY=:0` is what works for me, usually. Check with `echo $DISPLAY` in a GUI terminal.

Comment: It did not work for me and I do not know if it is true but I have found info that in Kubuntu 18.10 start.d is no longer used so scripts there are not working that is why I am trying with /lib/systemd/system-sleep/